# I can no longer access my Dell EMC N1124T-on through its GUI interface

Tags: switch, ethernet, http-proxy

We configured and set up our Dell EMC with a Putty interface first and went through the Set up wizard and gave it a static IP. Then joined it to our network and Deployed it into our IDF. Accessed it remotely through the Dell GUI OpenManage interface to further configure the ports. At a later date we attempted to log back into it through the GUI to retrieve a back up but the IP that we static and reserved in our DHCP no longer connected us to the Switch. I physically went to the Switch and plugged in with a Micro USB-B and logged into the Putty terminal of the device and pulled up the IP interface info and still showed the Static IP we assigned it. How can we have access to at one point and then lose it? did it lose its HTTP(S) certificate? Reading through the User guide for the switch doesn't provide any way of retrieving or resolving this issue using a terminal interface.

Comment: This could be a routing issue; a firewwall (ACL) issue, or something else. You need to edit your question and add the entire switch configuration - sanitized- using the preformatted option. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: *the IP that we static and reserved in our DHCP no longer connected us to the Switch* - Make sure that that IP address still resolves to the switch's MAC address. If there's a collision the switch might unbind the address somewhat silently.

Comment: since you can access the switch from the console, can you try to make one of the empty ports of the switch access your management VLAN and give your laptop an IP address from the same subnet and try to access it locally? If you can, It will make sure that there is an issue on the network as stated by JFL in the first comment.